# How do I configure postgres's authorization settings in nixos?

Tags: configuration, postgresql, nixos

On nixos, I face a postgres error `psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"` similar error to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306770/pg-peer-authentication-failed), and would like to edit the authentication settings to resolve the issue as described in an answer there:

> edit pg_hba.conf to use md5 password authentication instead of peer authentication for unix sockets (local connection type) so Pg accepts password authentication

I have resolved this same error previously on ubuntu by editing authorization configuration in that `pg_hba.conf` file. But my issue now is that **nixos does not appear to have such an `pg_hba.conf` to edit.**

**How do I make the corresponding postgres authorization configuration change in nixos?**

I noticed [this](https://github.com/NixOS/nixos/blob/master/modules/services/databases/postgresql.nix) postgres.nix file on github which appears to do something with `pg_hba.conf`, or at least contains the string, but I do not understand how to change my authentication settings from that. Also I have only  used the one main configuration file `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` and this appears to be a separate module, at `nixos/modules/services/databases/postgresql.nix`.

Comment: Have you searched http://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#postgres

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I had not seen that, but did end up using services.postgresql.authentication, which appeared in those linked search results.

Comment: This 'peer authentication failed' error seems to be resolved by setting services.postgresql.authentication as described in answer below, but the solution of this issue uncovered a 'psql: FATAL: role “postgres” does not exist' error, which is described in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45122893/nixos-error-psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following this [example configuration](https://github.com/cstrahan/nixos-config/blob/master/configuration.nix), I set the NixOS option `services.postgresql.authentication`.

I managed to get past the 'peer authentication failed' error when the postgres section of my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` had been set to

```
  # postgres
  services.postgresql.enable = true;
  services.postgresql.package = pkgs.postgresql94;
  services.postgresql.authentication = lib.mkForce ''
    # Generated file; do not edit!
    # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
    local   all             all                                     trust
    host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
    host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
    '';
```

Comment: This still works.

Comment: And query logging? I'm loving Nix but looking for these configuration related issues is fresh hell. :-)